# Logarithmic Axis issue with HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

We are comparing multiple series using logarithmic scale. Most of the time the chart looks fine and scales correctly to min/max of the data. In the example below the top series is cut off. The only thing that changes is the data. If we change the time period to any of the other options, it will re-scale correctly, going back to 1Y has the same problem. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

The second question I have is about the logic of the grid lines/labels when in log scale. Shouldn't by default the steps be based on Log(10) for example [0.10%, 1%, 10%, 100%, 1000%]? Is there a config option to set this? In the example below the default [0.10, 0.20, 0.40, 1.00] doesn't make much sense.

**This is what the labels/ticks should always look like:** jsfiddle.net/TeTMw/1

[image: Log scale issue]

**EDIT:**

Here is the highcharts code that looks like is causing this bug. Would be great if you could help fix this issue.

```
// Second case: We need intermediary ticks. For example 
            // 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 40 etc. 
        } else if (interval >= 0.08) {
            var roundedMin = mathFloor(min),
                intermediate,
                i,
                j,
                len,
                pos,
                lastPos,
                break2;

            if (interval > 0.3) {
                intermediate = [1, 2, 4];
            } else if (interval > 0.15) { // 0.2 equals five minor ticks per 1, 10, 100 etc
                intermediate = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8];
            } else { // 0.1 equals ten minor ticks per 1, 10, 100 etc
                intermediate = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
            }

            for (i = roundedMin; i < max + 1 && !break2; i++) {
                len = intermediate.length;
                for (j = 0; j < len && !break2; j++) {
                    pos = log2lin(lin2log(i) * intermediate[j]);

                    if (pos > min && lastPos <= max) {
                        positions.push(lastPos);
                    }

                    if (lastPos > max) {
                        break2 = true;
                    }
                    lastPos = pos;
                }
            }
```

Comment: How do you use compare with logarithmic axis? In Highstock for logarithmic scale only positive values are allowed. Could you recreate example on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's a known issue that log axes may be cut off in Highcharts 1.3.0. This will be fixed with 1.3.1, released later this week. See https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1666 .
2. For the Y axis tick interval, see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval. By default, the tickInterval is null, so the layout of the ticks is determined by tickPixelInterval. In your specific chart for example, if we skipped 0.20 and 0.40, the ticks would become too widespread for the default tickPixelInterval of 72.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Torstein. My second question was not about the tickInterval spacing, but having the option to force log scale to always be log10 [.01, .10, 1, 10, 100]? I don't see how [0.4, 0.10, 0.20, 0.40, 1.00] for the labels/steps is useful with the data shown above?

Comment: Here is how I expect the data above to always be displayed in log scale http://jsfiddle.net/TeTMw/1/

Comment: Regarding your second question, you need to recalculate values, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/TeTMw/2/